# How to display random multiple images not repeatedly in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can display only the first div and can't figure out how to display the rest of the div in randomly. Thanks in advance!

/* here is My JS*/

```
  var img_array = ["bomb.gif", "frown.gif", "grim.gif", "smile.gif"];

  /* run function every 'set up' time */
  setInterval(function() {
    randomImages();
  }, 2500);

  /* Generate random images and display from the array */
  function randomImages() {
    var randomImage =
      img_array[Math.floor(Math.random() * img_array.length)];

    var imgNode = document.querySelector(".imgsrc");

    imgNode.classList.remove("random");
    imgNode.classList.add("transitioning-src");

    setTimeout(() => {
      imgNode.src = randomImage;
      imgNode.classList.remove("transitioning-src");
      imgNode.classList.add("random");
    }, 500);

    document.querySelector(".imgsrc").src = randomImage;
  }
```

Comment: Can you show us your HTML too please ? :)

Comment: <ul id="random">
      <li class="logo"><img src="bomb.gif" class="imgsrc" alt="" /></li>
      <li class="logo"><img src="smile.gif" class="imgsrc" alt="" /></li>
      <li class="logo"><img src="frown.gif" class="imgsrc" alt="" /></li>
      <li class="logo"><img src="grim.gif" class="imgsrc" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>

Comment: @saw Don't give ur html in comment just **edit** your question and put it there.

Comment: I think you update the same element all the time. You choose the image randomly but not the html element

Comment: Just a first comment, your function will not understand what is `img_array` because you defined it ouside the function !

Comment: @KévinHuang - No problem with that

Comment: @KévinHuang Not sure, it's defined with var, it's accessible on child scope

Comment: @saw - It is the DOM node you need to select and show randomly, not the `src` of the first element, because you already have all your images in your HTML.

Comment: @KévinHuang - Thanks. I can't still figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments, it is the DOM `<li>` node you need to select and show randomly, not the src of the first `img` element, because you already have all your images in your HTML. There an example:

```js
const imgList = ['bomb.gif', 'frown.gif', 'grim.gif', 'smile.gif'];

/* Run function every 'set up' time */
setInterval(function() {
  randomImages();
}, 2500);

/* Show random image */
function randomImages() {
  const img = document.querySelector('ul#random > li.logo > img');
  const nextSrc = imgList[Math.floor(Math.random() * imgList.length)];
  
  img.src = nextSrc;
  img.alt = nextSrc;
}
```

```html
<ul id="random">
  <li class="logo">
    <img src="bomb.gif" class="imgsrc" alt="bomb.gif" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

But you can also use your image array and update the `src` attribute, but one `<li>` suffice:

```js
/* Run function every 'set up' time */
setInterval(function() {
  randomImages();
}, 2500);

/* Show random <li> */
function randomImages() {
  const liNodes = document.querySelectorAll('ul#random > li.logo');
  const next = Math.floor(Math.random() * liNodes.length);
  
  for (let i in liNodes) {
    const li = liNodes[i];
    
    if (li instanceof HTMLElement) {
      li.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
  
  liNodes[next].style.display = '';
}
```

```html
<ul id="random">
  <li class="logo">
    <img src="bomb.gif" class="imgsrc" alt="bomb.gif" />
  </li>

  <li class="logo" style="display:none" >
    <img src="smile.gif" class="imgsrc" alt="smile.gif" />
  </li>

  <li class="logo" style="display:none" >
    <img src="frown.gif" class="imgsrc" alt="frown.gif" />
  </li>

  <li class="logo" style="display:none" >
    <img src="grim.gif" class="imgsrc" alt="grim.gif" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I wanna display all the logos and randomly choose from an array. So now i'm trying to figure it out from ur comment above "randomly choose my html" and show the random images. I appreciate ur time!

Comment: Thanks @iArcadia - I can figure out now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all. Now my image is displaying randomly from the array. But still figure it out not repeatedly the image.

```js
 var img_array = [
        "laugh.jpg",
        "sad-face.jpg",
        "smiley.jpg",
        "artists.jpg",
        "detective.jpg",
        "monster.jpg",
        "smileyface.jpg",
        "tear.jpg",
        "tongue.jpg"
      ];
      
      /* run function every 'set up' time */
      setInterval(function() {
        randomImages();
      }, 1500);

      /* Generate random images and display from the array */
      function randomImages() {
        var randomImage =
          img_array[Math.floor(Math.random() * img_array.length)];

        /* randomly choose from html element */
        var arrayImg = document.getElementById("random").children;

        var randomArrayImg =
          arrayImg[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayImg.length)];



        randomArrayImg.src = randomImage;

        // document.querySelector(".imgsrc").value = randomImage;
      }
```

```css
#random {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 1000px;
        margin: 50px auto;
      }

      img {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
      }
```

```html
<div id="random">
      <img src="laugh.jpg" class="imgsrc" alt="" />

      <img src="sad-face.jpg" class="imgsrc" alt="" />

      <img src="detective.jpg" class="imgsrc" alt="" />

      <img src="tongue.jpg" class="imgsrc" alt="" />

      <img src="tear.jpg" class="imgsrc" alt="" />
  </div>
```